# Two-sample t test with before and after experiment data

Tags: t-test, experiment-design, two-sample

I have data with the following columns:
Person id, achievement before treatment, achievement after treatment (timewise)

Each person is put into a control or treatment group. Because the data is collected at different times (before and after the time at which treatment was implemented), even those who are in the control group have different achievements "before" and "after treatment."

I want to see the effect of treatment on achievement. I thought about using 2-sample t-test (on just after treatment data), but I'm not sure how to incorporate before-treatment data here. I am new to this field, so any help would be appreciated! (Please dumb it down for me!)

Comment: You would treat the control arm similarly, i.e. calculate to - from for all subjects and the compare these differences between the two groups by a Wilcoxon two-sample test or similar.

Comment: One possible solution is to calculate the difference between the pre and post scores thus this is a measure of improvement between the first and second test.  Then perform a 2 sample t-test with on the differences.  This will then indicate whether the treatment group differs from the control group.